# Configure virtual host, for apache on different port than default

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost

How do I configure virutal host so that I donot have to add port to the url ?
Now that I am running apache on different port (88)
[I Want to use 
http://my.local.com](http://my.local.com)  instead of
http://my.local.com:88

Answer (score 1):

If the server is behind a router (like on your home network) you can use port forwarding to forward traffic coming in on port 80 to the server on port 88.

Every router admin area is different, but usually you type 192.168.1.1 (your "gateway") into a browser, enter your credentials, then navigate to Port Forwarding. On some routers it's under a separate area, but this should be enough to get you within a few clicks.

In this case Apache would still listen on port 88.

Answer (score 0):

Of course no, you can't. As the URL is in the client, it doesn't know on which port your Apache is running.
By default, http use 80/tcp. If you want to use 88/tcp, your clients must change their ports.

I can suggest to derivatives :

- A redirect in your Apache from 80 to 88 (http://my.local.com is redirected to http://my.local.com:88)
- In the firewall a port redirect from 80 to 88.